# Class Level and Object Level lock synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, static

```
class MyClass
{
    public synchronized void print() {}

    public static synchronized void buffer() {}
}
```

Making static object synchronized makes a CLASS level object where only one Thread can access this. The class has both static and non-static Synchronized methods.

1. Can other threads(Thread-B) access **non-static** synchronize methods() via **object lock** while another Thread (Thread-A) using static synchronized (Acquiring a **class level lock**) method?
2. I hope non of the threads access any of the static synchronized methods until (Thread-B) release the lock.

Answer (score 4):

The answers to both your questions are "yes": static-level locks do not block instance-level `synchronized` methods, and they apply to all static `synchronized` methods.

Generally, though, synchronizing on the class is discouraged, because it leaves your class exposed to an infinite wait attack. The perpetrator synchronizes on the class, preventing all your static `synchronized` methods from running. A better approach is to make a private object for locking, and `synchronize` on it, like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public synchronized void print() {}

    private static Object staticLock = new Object();
    public static void buffer() {
        synchronized(staticLock) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Same goes for synchronizing the instance methods: if the class is to be used in potentially non-cooperative environment, you are better off with a private object for locking.

Comment: Is that attack important if no untrusted code is running in the same VM?

Comment: @immibis No, if all the code that runs on the VM is yours, you can safely ignore this. The only place where this may be important is when you build a library for use in a massive distribution, or when you give it to developers who do not have a direct channel of communication to you.

Comment: Who would think it was a good idea to synchronize on a random class object that wasn't theirs, anyway?

Comment: @immibis Someone who would like to cause harm to your system - for example, by keeping your communication library that synchronizes on one of its public classes from acknowledging a message from the server, to block your library at the point when it needs to update one of its critical files, or do something equally evil.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I meant in the non-malicious case. It seems like a bad thing to do exactly because it blocks synchronized static methods.

Answer (score 1):

In short:

- non-static methods use the current object's lock (only one thread per object)
- static methods use the associated `Class` object (there is one per class, so, only one therad per `Class` object)

It's important to take into account erasure:

```
// If you have this:

class MyClass<T> {

    static synchronized myMethod() { ... }

}

MyClass<Integer> objInt = new MyClass<Integer>();

MyClass<String> objString = new MyClass<String>();

// Then only one thread will be able to execute myMethod(),
// even when ojbInt and ObjString are not "exactly" the "same"
// class in compilation time
```

Answer (score 0):

**static locks**
synchronized(YourClass.class/class object)

**instance locks**
synchronized(this/instance object)
both are not mutually exclusive, both thread will run concurrently